# Having trouble animating SVG rect's opacity using Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm using the Raphael library and trying to animate the opacity of a rectangle from 0 to 1.

Here's the code I've written:

```
    this.myRect.attr( 'opacity', 0);
    this.myRect.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

This does not work, and I believe it's the animation line which is incorrect as I can set the initial attribute to a lower value and it is noticeable when I run the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I just figured this out after running into it myself. the property is "fill-opacity" not fill. so use

```
     node.animate({ "fill-opacity": "0.9" }, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#'+this.Myrect.node.id).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);

try this way

Comment: I'd use `$(myRect.node)` as it doesn't query the DOM and doesn't require the rect element to have an ID. Also, you may add that this answer requires the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the issue with your code stems from using `this.myrect.`. I'm assuming that you have declared myRect as `paper.rect(...)`, if so why would you need to use `this`.

[Have a look at this quick JsFiddle I mocked up](http://jsfiddle.net/GQKWZ/1/) it basically it demonstrates that you should use `rect.animate()`(or indeed some other element) but not `this`. From my personal experience `this` is used when attaching events to objects.